# Python JSON Parsing through list and check condition

Tags: python

I have the below JSON output in python , I want to read through the list and find the value of Index which is not equal to  "alias": "READ_PRD" and "alias": "WRITE_PRD" and "alias": ".kibana" and store the value in a variable.

In below case It is same value twice so store only once else store both the values.

How do I achieve this.

```
[
  {
    "alias": "READ_PRD",
    "index": "pI1",
    "filter": "-",
    "routing.index": "-",
    "routing.search": "-"
  },
  {
    "alias": "write_PRD",
    "index": "pI1",
    "filter": "-",
    "routing.index": "-",
    "routing.search": "-"
  },
  {
    "alias": ".kibana",
    "index": ".k_1",
    "filter": "-",
    "routing.index": "-",
    "routing.search": "-"
  },
  {
    "alias": "READ_STG",
    "index": "pI2",
    "filter": "-",
    "routing.index": "-",
    "routing.search": "-"
  },
  {
    "alias": "WRITE_STG",
    "index": "pI2",
    "filter": "-",
    "routing.index": "-",
    "routing.search": "-"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your specific issue?

Comment: basically I want this "index": "pI2" as output but if this index has 2 values,store those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the JSON is a string called `a` the following filters by a blacklist

```
import json
a = """
[]
"""
j = json.loads(a)
blacklist = ['READ_PRD', 'write_PRD', '.kibana']
items = [item for item in j if item['alias'] not in blacklist]
print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks I am quite new to python and this really looks an elegant solution, but when I run thru' this I get error.
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
When I check the type it is <class 'list'> so this is the problem.

Comment: Which one? I added a placeholder for `a` above, does it still occur if you replace `[]` with your  JSON structure?

Comment: Not sure what exactly this is doing a = """
[]
""", When I try this my list gets empty ?

Comment: and I am sorry I am in really initial stage , my code...
    r7_res=r7.json()
    print (type (r7_res))

    r7_res = """
        []
        """

    j = json.loads(r7_res)
    blacklist = ['READ_PRD', 'write_PRD', '.kibana']
    items = [item for item in j if item['alias'] not in blacklist]
    print(items)

Comment: The added code is a placeholder for a string containing JSON. It is empty because I didn't want to paste the whole thing in there. If you replace `[]` with your JSON (as shown in the question) it should print a list of filtered items.

Comment: Hi .. this solution works but one thing I forgot to mention, the o/p above if the index is matching with index of READ_PRD, 
I don't want that. ex. if READ_STG index is "pI1" matching with READ_RRD i.e. "pI2", I don't need that.

Comment: @Sushant either update your question or expand upon this answer. This seems to elegantly answer your question as it is currently written

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your accepted conditions for alias in a `set` for easy lookup, and then you can do a membership check:

```py
acceptable = {'READ_PRD', 'WRITE_PRD', '.KIBANA'}

for item in x:
    if item.get('alias', '').upper() not in acceptable:
        print(item)

   {
      "alias": "READ_STG",
      "index": "pI2",
      "filter": "-",
      "routing.index": "-",
      "routing.search": "-"
   },
   {
      "alias": "WRITE_STG",
      "index": "pI2",
      "filter": "-",
      "routing.index": "-",
      "routing.search": "-"
   }
```

The `str.upper()` call is to account for differences in capitalization

Or, using a `filter` statement:

```py
list(filter(lambda y: y.get('alias', '').upper() not in acceptable, x))
[
   {
      "alias": "READ_STG",
      "index": "pI2",
      "filter": "-",
      "routing.index": "-",
      "routing.search": "-"
   },
   {
      "alias": "WRITE_STG",
      "index": "pI2",
      "filter": "-",
      "routing.index": "-",
      "routing.search": "-"
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi .. this solution works but one thing i forgot to mention, the o/p above if the index is matching with index of READ_PRD, I don't want that. ex. if READ_STG index is "pI1" matching with READ_RRD, I don't need that.

Comment: I would update the question to be a bit more clear, then. As the question sits, you just want to avoid `alias` being `'READ_PRD', 'WRITE_PRD', '.KIBANA'`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df.query("alias not in ['.kibana', 'write_PRD', 'READ_PRD']")[['alias', 'index']].to_dict(orient='records')
```

output

```
[{'alias': 'READ_STG', 'index': 'pI2'}, {'alias': 'WRITE_STG', 'index': 'pI2'}]
```